# Is it possible to create TouchDelegates for multiple children?

Tags: android, android-view, hittest

I have a `LinearLayout` that contains multiple `ImageButton`s and `TextViews`.  Something like this:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------+-------+ <- LinearLayout
|    i    |     i     |     text here     |   i   |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+-------+
```

These items are hard to tap.  I want to increase their tappable area.  It seems as if `TouchDelegate` is the proper way to do this.

However, `view.getParent().setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(r, child))` is a 1:1 mapping, not a 1:Many mapping.  So how would one solve this problem when a `View` has multiple children that each need to be tappable beyond their bounds?

Comment: Have you experimented with extending the TouchDelegate class? One with a few overrides and property to store and report to many children?

Comment: I have not tried that.  That seems worth looking at.